# enable logging in typeorm with nestjs

Tags: logging, nestjs, typeorm

I have a provider module for dB  connection  with typeorm configuration like so

```
import { DatabaseType } from 'typeorm';
import { Logger, Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule, TypeOrmModuleAsyncOptions } from'@nestjs/typeorm';
import { MongoConfigModule } from '../../../config/database/mongo/config.module';
import { MongoConfigService } from '../../../config/database/mongo/config.service';
import { TypeOrmLoggerContainer } from '../../../common/logger/typeorm-logger-container';
 @Module({
   imports: [
      TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
        imports: [MongoConfigModule],
        useFactory: async (mongoConfigService: MongoConfigService) => ({
    type: mongoConfigService.mongo_type as DatabaseType,
    logger: new TypeOrmLoggerContainer(),
    logging: true,
    url: mongoConfigService.mongo_url,
    useUnifiedTopology: mongoConfigService.mongo_useUnifiedTopology,
    entities: [
      __dirname + '/../../../models/**/entities/*{.entity.ts,.entity.js}',
    ],
  }),
  inject: [MongoConfigService],
  } as TypeOrmModuleAsyncOptions),
 ],
 })
export class MongoDatabaseProviderModule {}
```

this is my typeormLoggerContianer here I am implementing logger from typeorm

```
  import { Logger, Logger as TypeOrmLogger, QueryRunner } from    'typeorm';
  
  export class TypeOrmLoggerContainer implements Logger {
  logQuery(query: string, parameters?: any[], queryRunner?: QueryRunner): any {
   console.log(query);
  }

 log(level: 'log' | 'info' | 'warn',message: any,queryRunner?:  QueryRunner): any {
   console.log(message);
  }

  logMigration(message: string, queryRunner?: QueryRunner): any {
   console.log(message);
 }

 logQueryError(error: string | Error,query: string,parameters?: any[],queryRunner?: QueryRunner,): any {
    console.log(query);
  }

logQuerySlow(time: number,query: string,parameters?: any[],queryRunner?:QueryRunner,): any {
    console.log(query);
  }

  logSchemaBuild(message: string, queryRunner?: QueryRunner): any {
    console.log(message);
  }
}
```

know I am using a custom wrapper around typeorm logger TypeOrmLoggerContainer
like this example here  https://typeorm.io/#/logging

the application builds successfully but no logs appear in the console when querying to the database using typeorm!

any clue how to fix this?

Comment: Can you add what a `TypeOrmLoggerContainer` looks like? And what your start logs look like?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel edited, my start logs work as normal all modules get initialized and it logs the start of the application

Comment: Maybe a dumb question, but do you import your `MongoDatabaseProviderModule` inside your App module ?

Comment: Also the only difference I see between your code and nestjs doc, is that you have your arrow function in async

Comment: @HartWoom, yes i did import MongoDatabaseProviderModule cause it's the connection to mongo db and the connection works and I get data from mongo but I can't log the quiries

Comment: I event replaced logger: new TypeOrmContainer() to  logger:'file' but  still doesn't log anything

Comment: Try adding `Connection` from typeorm in the inject array of your module maybe ?

Comment: ok now i added Connection from typeorm in inject array but then  then the connection to mongodb got  broke

Comment: The logger code/config is fine. Just tried it myself, but we use postgres. Maybe a problem with mongo specifically? Also what version of typeorm are you using? Tested using "typeorm": "^0.3.7",

Comment: i am not sure of the version ,
back then i gave up and used another logger,
but it was working with postgres but not with mongodb as you suggested.